# MIN() Function in SQL

Tags: sql, min

Need help with Min Function in SQL

I have a table as shown below.

```
+------------+-------+-------+
|   Date_    | Name  | Score |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 2012/07/05 | Jack  |     1 |
| 2012/07/05 | Jones |     1 |
| 2012/07/06 | Jill  |     2 |
| 2012/07/06 | James |     3 |
| 2012/07/07 | Hugo  |     1 |
| 2012/07/07 | Jack  |     1 |
| 2012/07/07 | Jim   |     2 |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to get the output like below

```
+------------+------+-------+
|   Date_    | Name | Score |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2012/07/05 | Jack |     1 |
| 2012/07/06 | Jill |     2 |
| 2012/07/07 | Hugo |     1 |
+------------+------+-------+
```

When I use the MIN() function with just the date and Score column I get the lowest score for each date, which is what I want. I don't care which row is returned if there is a tie in the score for the same date. Trouble starts when I also want name column in the output. I tried a few variation of SQL (i.e min with correlated sub query) but I have no luck getting the output as shown above. Can anyone help please:)

Query is as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
A.USername, A.Date_, A.Score 
FROM TestTable AS A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Date_,MIN(Score) AS MinScore 
FROM TestTable 
GROUP BY Date_) AS B 
ON (A.Score = B.MinScore) AND (A.Date_ = B.Date_);
```

Comment: @ Chandu I am using MS Access, but I would prefer to have a solution in ANSI SQL.

Comment: @radashk SELECT DISTINCT A.USername, A.Date_, A.Score
FROM TestTable AS A INNER JOIN (SELECT Date_,MIN(Score) AS MinScore
FROM TestTable
GROUP BY Date_)  AS B ON (A.Score = B.MinScore) AND (A.Date_ = B.Date_);

Comment: brr..that's messy. Can you use http://sqlfiddle.com please

Comment: Do you have a primary key in your table? If not, can you add one?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I do not have a PK , but I can sure add one. How would that work though

Comment: @irfarino Your query will return multiple rows for a date if multiple players are tied with the lowest score. If I understand the OP correctly, this is not what he wants.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt,I want only one row returned when multiple players are tied with the score on the same day.

Comment: @radashk, sorry will repost the query so it is not messy :)

Comment: So you want the lowest score for the oldest date? or the oldest date of the lower score? for each user of course

Comment: @radashk, he wants the lowest score and associated name for each **date**. If the scores are tied, he just wants one of them regardless of who it is.

Comment: @IT ppl Thanks for fixing the query!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this solution:

```
SELECT a.date_, MIN(name) AS name, a.score
FROM tbl a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date_, MIN(score) AS minscore
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY date_
) b ON a.date_ = b.date_ AND a.score = b.minscore
GROUP BY a.date_, a.score
```

[SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad890/2/0)

This will get the minimum score per date in the `INNER JOIN` subselect, which we use to join to the main table. Once we join the subselect, we will only have dates with names having the minimum score (with ties being displayed).

Since we only want one name per date, we then group by `date` and `score`, selecting whichever name: `MIN(name)`.

If we want to display the `name` column, we must use an aggregate function on `name` to facilitate the `GROUP BY` on `date` and `score` columns, or else it will not work (We could also use `MAX()` on that column as well).

Comment: Awesome, never occured to me to use the function on the name column!

Comment: http://www.irfarino.com/2012/07/08/select-unique-record-for-minmax-function-in-sql/?preview=true&preview_id=15&preview_nonce=cd4f3546dc

Answer (score 1):

Please learn about the `GROUP BY` functionality of RDBMS.

```
SELECT Date_,Name,MIN(Score)
FROM T
GROUP BY Name
```

This makes the assumption that EACH NAME and EACH date appears only once, and this will only work for MySQL.

To make it work on other RDBMSs, you need to apply another group function on the Date column, like  MAX. MIN. etc

Comment: what you said does not work,tried that allready, as soon as you add a column that makes rows distinct(i.e. Name) it will return all rows. I need all three columns in my result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.Name, T.Date_, MIN(T.Score) as Score FROM T 
 GROUP BY T.Date_
```

Comment: This will return all rows with the minimum score per `date` and `name` combination.

Comment: I thought that was intended..sry

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer is not corrected as pointed out by JNK in comments

```
SELECT Date_,MAX(Name),MIN(Score)
FROM T
GROUP BY Date_
```

Here I am using MAX(NAME), it will pick one name if two names were found with the same goal numbers.

This will find Min score for each day (no duplicates), scored by any player. The name that starts with Z will be picked first than the name that starts with A.

Edit: Fixed by removing group by name

Comment: This will select all rows as well: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad890/4/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad890/4/0)

Comment: @ZaneBien thanks for correction. Fixed. Removed group by name.

Comment: The revised solution will not work either. What it's doing is it's selecting the highest name in the alphabet per date, and the minimum score per date. But there is no correlation between the `MAX()` and `MIN()`. Look here: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad890/5/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad890/5/0): Jim is chosen for the third date, but that is not Jim's corresponding score. It is someone else's.

Comment: @ZaneBien OP said, the name is not important as long as it is the minim score. So if two players scored minimum, you can pick either of them. That's why MAX(name) just leave out all other names. We can use Min(name) too.

Comment: I don't think you actually understand how grouping works.  OP still wants the name to be associated with the score, and this solution shows a score and a name which are completely unrelated to each other.